# Oscilloscope cap replacement - Panasonic vs Nichicon

Tags: capacitor

I have to replace a bunch of capacitors on the acquisition block of a portable digital oscilloscope and one of the requirements is that the capacitors have beto be small.

I am trying to decide between Panasonic KS/KA series and Nichicon UMW.

Can anyone advise which one suits better my application?

Panasonic KS/KA is a standard series. Nichicon UMW is an audio series.

I have a preference for Panasonic as I can buy locally. But not sure Audio would be of any benefit here.

Panasonic https://docs-apac.rs-online.com/webdocs/0027/0900766b800274c4.pdf

Nichicon http://nichicon-us.com/english/products/pdfs/e-umw.pdf

Comment: What do the capacitors **do** in your circuit? Decoupling?  AC coupling?  What frequencies do they have to handle?

Comment: I prefer capacitors with bamboo fiber dielectric. If you use anything else in your scope, the signal will become muddy and indistinct, and it will lose its warmth.

Comment: Nope, I am not asking about mechanical space. I am asking between two series of capacitors characteristics. One is standard and one is audio rated. How those will perform on an oscilloscope acquisition system that has to deal with signals up to 20MHz.

Comment: It depends on where they are in the signal chain as to whether or not it matters.

Comment: Ah.  Electrolytics.  Probably not part of actually handling the signal.  Datasheets don't have enough info to really say anything.

Comment: Considering the analog board is separate from the power supply. They are all coupling the 5V rail to ground before it reaches any of the amps and ics. I don't think they are filtering the signal that comes in, but mostly filtering the current that goes to the components that process the signals. As they do not seem to deal with signals I suspect I could just use a standard rated cap here. No need to go expensive and do low ESR or audio stuff, right?

Comment: Specifications of importance: Capacitance, voltage rating, temperature, ESR. Compare specifications to the OEM capacitors.

Comment: Do you have a capability to compare specifications? To me they look identical. Buy the least expensive ones.

Comment: If you want peace of mind consider using Aluminum Polymer Electrolytics instead. In general their specs are much better, they are much more reliable and are supposed to last much longer.

Comment: *They are all coupling the 5V rail to ground* That means they're **decoupling** or **bypass** capacitors. *...filtering the current that goes to the components that process the signals.* No, they're **decoupling the supply voltage**, these caps stabilize the supply voltage when the chips draw pulsed currents from the supply, which is something all digital chips do all the time. Just choose capacitors that look similar and have a similar size to what is used on the board originally. No need to use "audio" caps or such.